# MySQL SQL command to query from one table with three same columns to another table

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

Sorry but I am not sure how to ask this question but I am working on a help desk application where I have tickets being created in one table.  I also have another table that stores the users.  My problem is with the tickets table, I have listed the user that created the ticket, the tech who will solve the ticket and a user that over sees the ticket.  All three users reference the users table.  So how do I can I query the tickets table and get all three users that reference the same table storing the users?

Table1: Tickets

```
1) Ticketnumber
2) EnteredBy             User 100
3) Issue
4) FixedBy               User 102
5) FixedByNotes
6) ResponsilbeUser       User 103
```

Table2: Users

```
1) UserID
2) UserName
```

What I can do now is something like this:

```
Select Ticketnumber, EnteredBy, Issue, UserName FROM Tickets INNER JOIN Users 
       ON Tickets.EnteredBy = Users.UserID
```

Thanks Steve

Comment: Executing the following query gives me an error

`Select Ticketnumber, EnteredBy, Issue, Reporters.UserName, Developers.UserName, Managers.UserName FROM Tickets
INNER JOIN Users AS Reporters ON Tickets.EnteredBy = Reporters.UserID
INNER JOIN Users AS Developers ON Tickets.FixedBy = Developers.UserID
INNER JOIN Users AS Managers ON Ticket.ResponsibleUser = Managers.UserID`

The program gives an error when I try to retreive the data.

`Text='<%# Eval("Reporters.UserName") %>'` 

(DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name `'Reporters'`.)

Comment: The above comment is actually a pending edit from Steve for his question. I thought of pasting it here. @Steve: It is better to either put these type of things as comment under your question or a specific answer. In this case since two answers are very similar I thought it would be more appropriate to have it as comment here.

Comment: @Steve: I have reviewed my query and fixed a few mistakes in the query in my answer. Please try again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extend current query to somewhat as follows:

```
Select Ticketnumber, Issue, Reporter.UserName, Developer.UserName, Manager.UserName FROM Tickets 
INNER JOIN Users AS Reporter ON Tickets.EnteredBy = Reporter.UserID 
INNER JOIN Users AS Developer ON Tickets.FixedBy = Developer.UserID 
INNER JOIN Users AS Manager ON Tickets.ResponsibleUser = Manager.UserID
```

Comment: It might be worthwhile adding three separate aliases for the three joins as otherwise it will be hard to tell which user is linked to which field.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You need alias for joint tables if you want to get all names:

```
Select Ticketnumber, Issue, Informers.UserName, Fixers.UserName, Supervisors.UserName FROM Tickets 
INNER JOIN Users Informers ON Tickets.EnteredBy = Users.UserID 
INNER JOIN Users Fixers ON Tickets.FixedBy = Users.UserID 
INNER JOIN Users Supervisors ON Ticket.ResponsibleUser = Users.UserID
WHERE...
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry as i am not able to understand your words, but if I assumed your need correctly.. just for a try this could help you..

if you need either of them i.e. all users who has either entered or fixed or saw an issue you can find by..

```
Select t.Ticketnumber, t.EnteredBy, t.Issue, u.UserID ,u.UserName FROM Tickets t
INNER JOIN Users u ON t.EnteredBy = u.UserID or t.FixedBy = u.UserID 
or t.ResponsibleUser = u.UserID;
```

And If you need all users who has entered, fixed and saw an issue you can find by..

```
Select t.Ticketnumber, t.EnteredBy, t.Issue, u.UserID ,u.UserName FROM Tickets t
INNER JOIN Users u ON t.EnteredBy = u.UserID and t.FixedBy = u.UserID 
and t.ResponsibleUser = u.UserID;
```